# ReportViewer duplicate toolbar on bottom of report?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportviewer

Is there a means to duplicate the toolbar so it shows at the **top and bottom** of the report page?  It can be a pain on long reports to scroll up to the top of the page in order to use various functions.

In my searching, I found [this link](http://devgig.blogspot.com/2009/05/extend-reportviewer-toolbar.html) about extending the ReportViewer control.  Has anyone worked with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely easy to recreate the toolbar.  I would recommend creating a custom toolbar, and placing it twice, where desired.

All the report functions can be called with ReportViewer.Function() calls.
You will need to handle Pagination, printing, export file.

To make this easy on you, here is a codeproject link to get you off your feet.

[Custom Toolbar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/custreport.aspx)

It is what I used to get started on creating my custom toolbar.